# Ask for file paths and copy specific data from multiple workbooks in a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub selfilecopypaste()
Dim filetoopen As Variant
Dim openfile As Workbook
Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 5

For count = 1 To 3

    filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="browse your file & import range", Filefilter:="excel files (*.xlsx*,*xlsx*")

    If filetoopen <> False Then
    Set openfile = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoopen)

        openfile.Sheets("low").Range("b2").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        openfile.Sheets("mid1").Range("i2:l2").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("di").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    openfile.Close False
End If
count = count + 1
i = i + 1

Next
End Sub
```

'I started learning VBA a week ago for my project and I'm stuck here. Please help.
'Workbooks have similar format. I want the data to be one below the other starting from row i =5.

Comment: `Range("di")` ---> `Range("D" & i)`.

Comment: It worked! thanks!